# How to set filters in column values of a table according to visitor

Tags: python, django

If the table name is 'product' and column name is 'subjects'. After fetching all the values of Products, how to set filters as requested by the visitor?

I am using Django.

Comment: Maybe something like this: `Product.objects.filter(subjects='user input')`.

Comment: Please refer Django documentation.. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Comment: Please note that querysets only solve one part of the problem. The user needs guidance from webbrowser request to output and is missing the overview.

Comment: do i need to set filter for every possible pairing of values...as user can request for single or multiple value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The short answer

Install [django-filter](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-filter/) and read it's documentation.

## The long answer

### Passing information

You need a way to pass the filters selected by the visitor's browser to Django. For this you can use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/) or you can build a [query string](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/snippet/2016/08/22/dealing-with-querystring-parameters.html) in the template.

### Collecting information

As with everything in Django, we collect request information and models in a view and return a response. I'm partial to class-based views, so I'll use those. There's plenty of examples of "form views" that process form input, so we'll stick to the query string way of things.

Each "[View](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.base/View/)" gets the request assigned to it as `View.request`, so that we can access it as `self.request` in any method of the view. Since we're going to show multiple objects of the same model, [ListView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) is a good place to start.

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class FilteredProductsView(ListView):
    model = Products
    context_object_name = 'products'
    template_name = 'view/products.html'
    filter_map = { 'name': 'subject__iexact', 'price': 'sales_price__lte' }

    def get_queryset(self):
        filter_kwargs = {}
        subject_filter = self.request.GET.get('name', None)
        if subject_filter:
             filter_kwargs[self.filter_map['name']] = subject_filter
        price_filter = self.request.GET.get('price', None)
        if price_filter:
             filter_kwargs[self.filter_map['price']] = float(price_filter)
        return self.model.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs) \
            if filter_kwargs else self.model.objects.all()
```

### Outputting information

On our filtered products view we defined the template name and also something called `context_object_name`. This is the name we can use in the template to render our model instances. `ListView` always defines the queryset as `object_list` for the template, but if the name makes more sense, it makes the template more readable.

So now we can do in our template `view/products.html`:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
        {% for product in products %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ product.subject }}</td>
                <td class="bg-success">{{ product.sales_price }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## Further reading

- [Query dicts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects)
- [Query sets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/)
- [Template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/)